# CSS scale several images to fit viewport keeping aspect ratio

Tags: css, image, scale, aspect-ratio

I'm creating a gallery where I want to list all images from an album on one page : [Big Picture style](http://www.boston.com/bigpicture/2014/04/survival_in_the_amazon.html) :

Unlike Big Picture, I want the images to **proportionally scale** to fit to the width of the container `div` (`.section-images`, which is set to `margin: auto 2em;` so its width is the width of the user's browser minus `2*2em`) as much as possible without making them larger than 90% height of the viewport.

As you imagine, a `400x600` portrait photo when scaled to fit the width would be so long the user would not see the whole image on screen, thats why I need to limit width scaling to not exceed 90% height.

```
<section class="section-images">
    <div class="image-box">
        <div class="image-large">
            <a href="#"><img foo1></a>
        </div>
        <div class="image-description">
          blabla1
        </div>
        ... MORE IMAGES WITH DESCRIPTONS ...
    </div>
    etc
</section>
```

Under each image I have the `.image-description`, the height of this will vary.

What is important is that at any one time a single image (so `.image-large`) should fit in the viewport, regardless of whether it is landscape or portrait.

I would like to do this using **only CSS** if possible, and only javascript if CSS is not possible.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

**Solution :**
(I stripped most of your containers to make it simple to understand and work with)

```css
html,
body,
.section-images {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.section-images {
  margin: auto 2em;
  text-align: center;
}
img {
  display: block;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 90%;
  margin: 20px auto;
}
```

```html
<section class="section-images">
  <a href="#"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/hMRnvUx.jpg" /></a>
  <div class="image-description">blabla3<br/>more blablah<br/>and more blablah</div>
  <a href="#"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/lBuIEDh.jpg" /></a>
  <div class="image-description">blabla2</div>
  <a href="#"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/k8BtMvj.jpgg" /></a>
  <div class="image-description">blabla3<br/>more blablah<br/>and more blablah</div>
</section>
```

---

**Explanation :**

This solution is based on the fact that percentages sizes (width and height) are relative the size of the parent element.

Considering `.section-images` is a direct child of `<body>` start by setting :

```
html, body, .section-images {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
}
```

So the **direct parent** of the images equals **viewport size**.

Then, you can size your images easily using :

```
img{
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:90%;
}
```

Images will **never exceed** 100% width and 90% height of viewport while keeping their **aspect ratio**. And they will stay in the flow of the document.

Comment: This is exactly what I need but unfortunately I can't get the parent of the child to be the direct child of the body since I'm working with a [slider](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) that requires a few div wraps.

Comment: @web-tiki There are several wraps before it gets to the actual image. So should I apply 100% height to every one of them?

Comment: This was really helpful and fortunately worked exactly for my purpose. I could even use 'calc(100% - 64px) and like such and 

Answer (score 16):

You can also use viewport units to do this without changing `html, body` for IE9+.

```
img {
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:90vh;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the height of the container `section-images` explicitly, and set its `overflow` to `hidden`.

Comment: Thank you for responding, however that does not satisfy the requirements.